# How to create a Azure Service Queue from Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I created an **Azure Function** which is triggered by **Azure Service Bus Queue**. I deployed the functions through the **Azure Pipeline** in Azure also.

My questions are:

1. I can create the queues manually in **Azure Portal**. But how can I create the **Azure Service Bus Queue** during the Build and Release pipeline?
2. I can add an App Configuration (Service Bus Connection String) manually for the **Azure Function**. But how can I add that during the build and release pipeline?

Azure Pipeline Tasks:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is many tasks in Release Pipeline you can use to create Azure Service Bus Queue:

- Azure CLI
- PowerShell
- ARM template deployment
- Terraform

Azure CLI or PowerShell could solve yours problems, you just must authorize in script and use any command you like to use - create Azure Service Bus and set configuration to Azure Functions.

There is example in CLI:

1. Create Azure Service Bus Queue (from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-cli#use-the-azure-cli-to-create-resources))

   ```
   # Create a resource group
   resourceGroupName="myResourceGroup"

   az group create --name $resourceGroupName --location eastus

   # Create a Service Bus messaging namespace with a unique name
   namespaceName=myNameSpace$RANDOM
   az servicebus namespace create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $namespaceName --location eastus

   # Create a Service Bus queue
   az servicebus queue create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --namespace-name $namespaceName --name BasicQueue

   # Get the connection string for the namespace
   connectionString=$(az servicebus namespace authorization-rule keys list --resource-group $resourceGroupName --namespace-name $namespaceName --name RootManageSharedAccessKey --query primaryConnectionString --output tsv)
   ```
2. Set settings to Azure Functions (from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#azure-cli))

   ```
   az functionapp config appsettings set --name <FUNCTION_APP_NAME> \
   --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> \
   --settings CUSTOM_FUNCTION_APP_SETTING=12345
   ```

Comment: I added an Azure CLI task and added the above PowerShell script. It worked.